# Authorize.net : This transaction has been declined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, authorize.net

**CreditCard Model**

```
def charge_cents!(cents)
  begin
    gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::AuthorizeNetGateway.new($installation[:authorize])
    response = nil
    Timeout::timeout(120.seconds) {
      response = gateway.purchase(cents, self.to_am_creditcard, {
        :order_id      => self.customer.contract_number[1..-1],
        :cust_id       => self.customer.contract_number[1..-1]
      }.merge(self.am_billing_address_hash))
    }
    return response
  rescue
    return response = nil
  end
end
```

**to_am_creditcard**

```
  def to_am_creditcard
    ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new({
      :number   => self.number,
      :month    => self.month,
      :year     => self.year,
      :first_name => self.first_name,
      :last_name  => self.last_name,
    })
  end
```

**am_billing_address_hash**

```
  def am_billing_address_hash
    {:billing_address => self.to_hash }
  end
```

Now, Take last credit card

```
1.9.3p484 :003 > @card = CreditCard.last
 => #<CreditCard id: 17263, crypted_number: "uXHr8wFYPvlaLWkB7hMltzex60ZtINOMH7EDB+/uSZU=\n", last_4: "4242", first_name: "test3", last_name: "test4", phone: "1234567890", customer_id: 66837, month: 7, year: 2017, address_id: 230222, created_at: "2014-07-11 03:36:21", updated_at: "2014-07-11 03:36:21">
```

and Now, use charge_cents method

```
1.9.3p484 :006 >  response = @card.charge_cents!(amount * 100.0)
 => #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0xbac6ce0 @params={"response_code"=>2, "response_reason_code"=>"2", "response_reason_text"=>"This transaction has been declined.", "avs_result_code"=>"U", "transaction_id"=>"6328764577", "card_code"=>"", "authorization_code"=>"", "cardholder_authentication_code"=>"", "action"=>"AUTH_CAPTURE"}, @message="This transaction has been declined", @success=false, @test=false, @authorization="6328764577", @fraud_review=false, @avs_result={"code"=>"U", "message"=>"Address information unavailable.", "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil}, @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil}>
```

**See : response_reason_text**  : Getting This transaction has been declined

I don't know why I am getting this error, It's working on test mode but when I remove a test mode then getting this error.

or, If any other way to integrate auth.net with ruby on rails 3.2 then please help for this with code.

**Update**
I am passing this data: 
CC Number : 4242424242424242
ExpireDate : 11/2015

Please Help Me.

Thanks, In Advance.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but if you're not running in test mode, the card may actually be validated against the data you're passing in which is dummy data...?

Answer (score 0):

First, when you specify Test Mode, the gateway only checks if the API Login and Transaction Key are correct and returns success if valid.  This is true for both the sandbox or production.  You should never use test mode in the sandbox.

Try using 4111111111111111 in the sandbox with test mode=false to test a transaction.

Comment: still getting transaction has been declined.

Comment: Are you testing against the sandbox, or a production account?

Comment: on production account and also test on sandbox account

Comment: A test card number would never work in production and one would expect to get a card decline.